# How can an illusion spell fool true seeing?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, illusion

A [*true seeing*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/true-seeing/) effect allows the creature to automatically "see through illusions," and many powerful monsters possess a constant ability that grants the monster an effect like *true seeing* (e.g. some [angels](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/angel/solar/), [demons](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/demon/glabrezu/), [devils](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/devil/erinyes/), [inevitables](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/inevitable/inevitable-zelekhut/), and even [dragons](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/dragons/linnorm/linnorm-crag/)).

Ideally, I'd like a way for a caster to create illusions that are *not* automatically seen through by an effect like *true seeing*. Alternatively, is there a convenient way—one that can be used in combat—for a caster to deactivate a foe's *true seeing* effect?

I am looking for spells, class features, feats, magic items, or anything else that will *either* make illusion spells immune to *true seeing* *or* suppress a *true seeing* effect.

(I am aware that the [*mind blank*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/mind-blank/) spell may affect a *true seeing* effect, but even if that works, an illusionist protected by the spell *mind blank* still creates [*silent image*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/silent-image/) effects that are seen through automatically by a *true seeing* effect! The spell *mind blank*, for example, isn't any help if the illusionist wants her [*hallucinatory terrain*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/hallucinatory-terrain/) spell to fool an army of [balors](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/demon/balor/)!)

Comment: Welcome to the site. Take the [tour]! You'll notice I edited this *a lot* (not because the original was *wrong* but because I liked the question and wanted it *even clearer*), so confirm that it's still asking what you want answered. I assumed the question was more about deceiving *true seeing* with spells *not* cast on the caster, hence the elimination of *mind blank* as a solution. If I've made a wrong assumption, please, pardon me, and edit the question more.  Thank you for participating and have fun.

Comment: In D&D 3.5e, which Pathfinder is based on, there is an Invisible Spell metamagic feat, which makes a spell effect invisible. Using this on a cloud spell was a commonly-suggested way to partially foil _true seeing_, since if you saw through the illusion, you just got an opaque cloud instead, while those “fooled” by it could see right through it. I do not know if Pathfinder has a similar option, but if it does, would that be an answer to the question you are interested in?

Comment: Thanks Hey I Can Chan, you was not mistaken on what i asked, you edit is a lot clearer

Comment: @KRyan With the asker having chimed in, I think it's safe for me to say that's a possibility, although that's *really* complicated and liable to have unintended consequences. (BTW, *Pathfinder* has a 3rd-party Invisible Spell feat.)

Answer (score 2):

RAW I'd say no. A "visual" illusion spell cannot fool a [True Seeing](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/true-seeing/) spell unless the illusion is more than 120 feet away and still visible at that range. (True Seeing has a range of 120 feet.) For big illusions that probably works at the outset but if the distance closes then the illusion falls apart visually.

Depending upon your acceptance of Psionics, there is a level 3 Telepath power called [False Sensory Input](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/psionic-powers/f/false-sensory-input/) (FSI) which you could target on a True Seeing creature to affect their vision (FSI explicitly states it fools True Seeing as it doesn't work on the target's eyes but rather their brain) then the combination of the illusion's sound, tactile, olfactory, and taste should completely counter True Seeing.
The drawback being you'd need to also be a Psion Telepath class level 5. Optionally if you have [Use Magical Device](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/use-magic-device/) and can find a Psion Telepath to make you a [dorje](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/equipment/psionic-items/dorjes/) (wand) with False Sensory Input (FSI) on/in it, then you could use the "Use a Scroll" option to "fake" having access to the FSI power and combine the dorje with any illusion to mess up True Seeing folk right good and proper!

Answer (score 1):

**Use reverse psychology**, start with mundane alterations or hiding and then put an illusion of some other kind on top of it, if you are trying to hide something use an illusion that would seem enticing, distracting, or an easy target, if trying to draw them in, use a camouflage illusion or something threatening. Demons tend to be arrogant use that against them.

Or course this relies on them knowing what the illusion is of, which depending on how your DM deals with true seeing they may not.